# CodeIgniter - Problems with <title> tag </ title>

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Good evening,

I have the following situation:

I have a login controller, which after registering user data in session variables it does the redirection. But before 
I redirect I have an array to send data to the "home" view (post login), but that's where the problem comes from, I 
notice that during the redirection it appears in the  in the browser the entire url, from when it arrives in 
the view is loaded the content of the array in the title tag correctly.
And analyzing vi that appears on all the links of the menu that are triggered!
Can someone give me some guidance on this? I'll be grateful.

Below the array and data passing:

```
$data = array (
    'meta_title' => $this->config->item('pages_title__login')
    );
$this->load->view ('setup/view_page_login', $data);
```

Below the destination view:

```
<head>
    <title> <?PHP echo $meta_title; ?> </title>
    <?PHP $this->load->view('metas/metas-login'); ?>
</head>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju67d.png)

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what is happening?

Comment: Okey,

follows print for better gripping.

Note the title of the page, this is exactly what appears when the function in the controller makes the redirect to the view. The entire url appears in the title, but when the view is fully loaded the text appears correctly, as I said before.

Comment: Never heard of or seen that before. Even if it was a nested view problem you close your title tag so it wouldn't appear there. Dunno.

Comment: still continues, even putting a normal text inside the tag, without the use of php.
This is happening when I click on links or use redirect

Comment: Tell you what, if you package your app in a minimal version enough for me to test in my local environment I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, I can try to send you a part of the reduced code, but if possible I get a more private contact with you

Comment: you can wetransfer it to alex@fagardesigns.com  ... just make sure it is enough to test the issue, but not so much that I have to install a bunch of crap ;)

Comment: quiet, there are few dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for your further information, try not to load a view inside a view. Try loading it inside the controllers index function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly like this:

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $this->config->item('pages_title__login'); ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: still continues, even putting a normal text inside the tag, without the use of php.
This is happening when I click on links or use redirect